# How can I get the current version of ddrescue?

Tags: apt, ddrescue

I am running an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS from a live DVD to use ddrescue on an old HDD.

When I do

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudp apt install gddrescue
```

I get version *1.22-1* which outputs a copyright year of 2017. However, [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#dir) talks about *version 1.26, 21 January 2022*.

How can I install the current version on a live Ubuntu? (Do I just need to download and burn another newer Ubuntu disc?)

Comment: It certainly helps, but I can only guess that the version *might* be newer if I download a new Ubuntu first.

Comment: Newer releases tend to have [newer packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gddrescue), so yes, get a newer release.

Comment: @mikewhatever, unfortunately, the newer release has version 1.23, which is over 4 years old.

Comment: @Rinzwind, well, I think that I should match the version I use as closely to the version described in the manual as possible. ;-) I am not installing 18.04/22.04, I am using a live DVD, so I am flexible there.

Comment: *"over 4 years old"* - So what? Is there a reason you need the newer version? This is a pretty basic utility. I can't imagine why using a newer version is beneficial unless you know for sure that the newer version contains something you actually need.

Comment: I provided an answer below to install the newest version from source. It's most likely not necessary though. If there's an actual reason you need the newer version, the answer is below. Otherwise, the exact build available from the repository has been tested and verified to work well with the system so it's probably best just to use that instead of my answer.

Comment: According to the changelog, the only noticeable difference would probably be the new `--command-mode` option and there's also a new `--format` option.

Comment: Also, `--same-file` and `--shift` options are new.

Comment: @mchid Thank you very much, you've convinced me to use the version I can install with my 22.04 live session now, since I do not need any of these functions. But your answer is very much appreciated as well, since it gives me very valuable background learning.

Comment: If you must have version 1.26, get ubuntu 22.10, which has [1.16-2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/gddrescue).

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Disclaimer: the following method is not recommended. The version available from the official repository using `apt` or the Software Center is the recommended version. Use the following only if you absolutely have a particular reason that the older version will not work.</sub>

Ddrescue is super easy to build from source if you need to install the latest version on an older Ubuntu release like 18.04. The following applies to version 1.26 (future users who may see this answer can find the latest URL [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddrescue/)).

Before you begin, run the following commands to install some prerequisites:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lzip lunzip build-essential
sudo apt build-dep gddrescue
```

<sub>note: if the last command doesn't work, you may need to uncomment the sources in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or enable source code through the "software and updates" GUI settings</sub>

Next, create a working directory:

```
mkdir DDRESCUE
cd DDRESCUE
```

Run the following commands to download the source:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddrescue/ddrescue-1.26.tar.lz
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-keyring.gpg
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ddrescue/ddrescue-1.26.tar.lz.sig
```

Verify the signature:

```
gpg --verify --keyring ./*gpg ./*sig
```

It should return the following

```
gpg: assuming signed data in './ddrescue-1.26.tar.lz'
gpg: Signature made Fri 21 Jan 2022 11:46:03 AM EST
gpg:                using DSA key 8FE99503132D7742
gpg: Good signature from "Antonio Diaz <ant_diaz@teleline.es>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 1D41 C14B 272A 2219 A739  FA4F 8FE9 9503 132D 7742
```

Extract the files:

```
tar xvf *lz
cd ddrescue-1.26
```

Now, build ddrescue:

```
./configure
make
make check
```

and if all goes well:

```
sudo make install
```

The `ddrescue` command should be installed to `/usr/local/bin/ddrescue`. You can simply execute `ddrescue` to run the command.

---

There are two things to remember when building from source. First, read the **README** file. Second, also read the **INSTALL** file.

Comment: It should be noted that you will be responsible for updating this version manually so keep an eye out for security updates. From what I gather, you'll be running from a Live USB anyhow so I guess that probably won't matter.

Comment: Good one so +1 but not beginner friendly so be careful  anyone goes with this . In this case I would use a 22.04 live session though.